# Wiring - Lights and Fan

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting

Here is what I want to accomplish. Install a light outside our backdoor, run electric to porch to recessed lights and ceiling fans. We would like to have the light outside the door on a switch, the recessed lights on a switch and the fans on a single switch. We currently have a switch box that currently has power coming into it (14-2). I was planning on running 14-2 from the switch box to the light outside the back door. I was thinking I would run 14-3 from the switch box to the junction box of the first fan. One of the conductors of the 14-3 will operate the two fans and the other would be used for the recessed lights. What does the inside of the switch box look like?

Does this sound right:

- Power Feed coming into box (14-2)

  - Black - 3 pigtails that will go to the 3 switches
  - White - capped together with 14-2 white and the 14-3 white
- 14-2 wire coming in from light outside back door

  - Black - Going to switch
  - White - capped together with (Power Feed) 14-2 white and the 14-3 white
- 14-3 wire that will operate the fans and recessed lights

  - Black - Going to switch that will control recessed lights
  - White - capped together with (Power Feed) 14-2 white and the (Door Light) 14-2 white
  - Red - Going to switch that will control fans

Comment: You have it pretty much figured out. I would just suggest having a separate junction box for the feeds to the can lights and fans. Making all those joints in the fan junction box itself could be a real problem and if you ever want to access the joints to add anything you would have to remove the fan. That would be a real pain. Good Luck!

Comment: That's a good point. So since this is going to be in the ceiling of the porch the box would need to be accessible somewhere below the ceiling line then?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately that may change the look of things if you have a box with a blank cover on it somewhere below the ceiling unless you cover it something. If that is objectionable then you should stick with your idea of making your joints in the ceiling fan J-box.